# lectura y escritura simultanea con open()

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy intentando con python,cargar un archivo `data.save` que esta en formato json,
lo que hago para abrirlo es
`archivo = open("data.save","r+")`,
por que quiero lectura y escritura a la vez,sin embargo cuando lo paso por
`objeto = json.load(archivo)` o `objeto = json.loads(archivoi.read())`
me sale un error como este:
**json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)**
el contenido de el archivo json es este:

```
{
    "id":6,
    "values":{
        "list":[0,1,3],
        "id":0
    }
}
```

y este mi codigo:

```
import json
from os.path import exists
if not(exists("data.save")):
    #si no existe el archivo lo creamos
    with open("data.save","w") as f:
        pass

archivo = open("data.save","r+")
if archivo.read() == "":
    objeto = {
        "id":6,
        "values":{
            "list":[0,1,3],
            "id":0
        }
    }
    json.dump(objeto,archivo) #esta parte no da error
else:
    objeto = json.load(archivo) #tambien he provado con json.loads(archivo.read())
```

Comment: creo que el error estan en el modo en el que abro el archivo,(`r+`)

Comment: pero no estoy seguro puede que el problema este en el `dump()` tambien aunque no salga ningun error

Comment: Es que ya lo has leido en el `if archivo.read() ==""`, por lo que para cuando se lo pasas a `json.load()` ya no hay nada más para leer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La causa inmediata del error es que primero lees el contenido completo del archivo con

```
if archivo.read() == "":
```

y luego se lo pasas a json para hacer el `load`, pero a esas alturas ya lo leistes todo:

```
objeto = json.load(archivo)
```

y json no encuentra nada con que armar el objeto pedido.

#### Demo

He tomado el programa y he eliminado el `if archivo.read()`

```
if not(exists("data.save")):
    #si no existe el archivo lo creamos
    with open("data.save","w") as f:
        pass

archivo = open("data.save","r+")
objeto = json.load(archivo)
print(objeto)
```

produce:

```
{'id': 6, 'values': {'list': [0, 1, 3], 'id': 0}}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### Otro enfoque

El propósito de tu código es cargar la configuración desde un archivo. Si el archivo no existe, lo mejor es crearlo y poblarlo de inmediato, como en este ejemplo:

```
import json
from os.path import exists

if not(exists("data.save")):
    #si no existe el archivo lo creamos
    with open("data.save","w") as f:
        objeto = {
            "id": 6,
            "values": {
                "list": [0, 1, 3],
                "id": 0
            }
        }
        json.dump(objeto, f)

with open("data.save","r+") as archivo:
    objeto = json.load(archivo) #tambien he provado con json.loads(archivo.read())
    print(objeto)
```

Acostumbra a abrir los archivos usando `with open() as nombre:`; es más simple.

Comment: lo pruebo ahora

Comment: muchas gracias,funciona a la perfeccion

Comment: no lo habri con with porque lo uso como variable global para todo un proyecto

Comment: @elweoncalvo como variable??? nunca coloques nombres reservados a tus variables!!

Comment: nombres reservados?

Comment: es un arbol de archivos que usa ese archivo en muchos archivos de el proyecto
es mil veces menos eficiente cada vez que valla usar este archivo abrirlo,que solo abrirlo una vez pero para todo el proyecto